# Converting string to list in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying convert this string to a python list using json.loader but it does not work.

```
"[[0,0,1,'Regulado',0,0,0],[0,0,1,'Nivel 1',0,0,0]]"
```

Comment: How  are you trying to do this? Post the code please

Comment: Hi Juan. It looks like you want to convert a string to a list. Is that correct? But your string does not look like it is in correct json format.

Comment: i trying first using the list function , that is: data="[[0,0,1,'Regulado',0,0,0],[0,0,1,'Nivel 1',0,0,0]]"  list(data). 
but that divides me character by character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON expects strings to be wrapped with double quotes; the single quotes in your example are causing the issue. If you know that you can just replace single with double, then you can do this:

```
In [26]: import json

In [27]: json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
Out[27]: [[0, 0, 1, 'Regulado', 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 'Nivel 1', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: @JUANFELIPEGIRALDOPINEDO Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can indicate to others that this is the correct answer by "accepting" it (clicking on the green check mark).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
x = eval("[[0,0,1,'Regulado',0,0,0],[0,0,1,'Nivel 1',0,0,0]]")
```

However, `eval` executes anything that is given to it, so be sure that your data don't come from malicious sources.

Comment: `import ast; ast.literal_eval(...)`

Comment: i would say json is a better option here due to the dangers of eval

Comment: @modesitt: I would say that too, just wan't sure it would parse it right.